# Execute task with windows Scheduled Task function

Tags: windows, automation, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to execute  a.bat file when my sessión closed. I cannot manage to make it. The set-up is as follows:

- General
  Execute either the session is open or closed
  Execute with the highest priviledges
- Triggers
  Execute daily at specific time
- Contitions
  None

Thank you!

I tried almost every option. I just want that the .bat runs on unattended mode

Comment: If the trigger is 'run at a specific time,' it should run when you are logged on. I would start by watching it in Task Scheduler to see if it actually triggers. And have you checked its history?

Comment: Hi R.J. Thank you for your answer. Yes I have checked it and it works. I only doesn´t work when the session is closed.